# javascript carousels: change position or scroll offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

While there are a ton of jQuery carousel plugins out there, I like to roll my own.

Reading through their code I've noticed that people manipulate either `scrollLeft` or position (`left: -100px`) in order to "move" the carousel.

Which one is better? Are there any performance benefits from one or the other?

---

example using scroll: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/

Comment: Good question. I wrote one myself last year and used position, rather than scroll offset and it worked just fine in IE 6 and up. I didn't try it with scrollLeft, though, so offhand I couldn't tell you if there would have been any performance benefits to it.

Comment: I used scroll until now and all seems fine. It does however slow up in some browsers when I load 100+ items in an infinite carousel :)

Comment: You could also do it by changing margin-left/right of the element. cycle plugin does the same thing and it works fine across all the browsers even will large number of items.

Comment: If you're putting 100+ items in a carousel, I'd wager a bet that a carousel probably isn't the best solution for you! :P